# Override Multivalue component in Adobe CQ

Tags: javascript, extjs, adobe, aem

I am currently working on a project where i will need to implement custom multifield component. I am really specific about the fact that i need to create nodes (which can be any number) when user specifies a value instead of key, value property.

I have currently added a pathField and a textbox.. which will be loaded using HTTP GET and when the user tries to input a value i would HTTP post from my custom extjs.

[image]

As shown above i would prefer the LHS to store entered values in nodes instead of RHS.
I have created the component of the following structure

As i'm going to make http calls and will not insert to jcr:content or any other path i've decided to remove the node reference "./multishort" below?

[image]

But when i do that the component loads but doesnt load the node properties. Can anyone suggest me how to handle this kind of loading nodes instead of properties?

Please see the sample js file below. Note: it doesnt have details to post yet i havent included since i was not sure where it has to be instantiated.

```
/**
 * @class Ejst.CustomWidget
 * @extends CQ.form.CompositeField
 * This is a custom widget based on {@link CQ.form.CompositeField}.
 * @constructor
 * Creates a new CustomWidget.
 * @param {Object} config The config object
 */
Ejst.CustomWidget = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.form.CompositeField, {

    /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.TextField
     */
    hiddenField: null,

    /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.ComboBox
     */
    allowField: null,

    /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.ComboBox
     */
    allowField2: null,

    /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.TextField
     */
    otherField: null,
    /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.TextField
     */
    shortField: null,
    /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.TextField
     */
    mediumField: null,
    /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.TextField
     */
    longField: null,

    /**
    * @private
    * @type CQ.Ext.form.TextField
    */
    linkURL: null,


    context1: null,

    price1: null,



    constructor: function(config) {

        config = config || { };
        var defaults = {
            "border": false,
            "layout": "table",
            "columns":2
        };
        config = CQ.Util.applyDefaults(config, defaults);
        Ejst.CustomWidget.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    },

    // overriding CQ.Ext.Component#initComponent
    initComponent: function() {
                alert("initComponent")
        Ejst.CustomWidget.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
           alert("after super initComponent")

        this.hiddenField = new CQ.Ext.form.Hidden({

            name: this.name
        });
        this.add(this.hiddenField);


        this.allowField = new CQ.form.Selection({



            type:"select",
            cls:"ejst-customwidget-1",
            listeners: {
                selectionchanged: {
                    scope:this,
                    fn: this.updateHidden
                }
            },
            optionsProvider: this.optionsProvider
            // optionsProvider:[{text:"en",value:"en"},{text:"fr",value:"fr"}]
        });
        this.add(this.allowField);


        //this is for test pathfield
        this.allowField2 = new CQ.form.PathField({

            type:"select",
            cls:"ejst-customwidget-2",
            listeners: {
                change: {
                    scope:this,
                    fn: this.updateHidden
                }
            },


            optionsProvider: this.optionsProvider
             //optionsProvider:[{text:"en",value:"en"},{text:"fr",value:"fr"}]
        });
        this.add(this.allowField2);


        this.otherField = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({

            cls:"ejst-customwidget-3",

            listeners: {
                change: {
                    scope:this,
                    fn:this.updateHidden
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(this.otherField);

    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#processPath
    processPath: function(path) {
        alert("processPath")
        console.log("CustomWidget#processPath", path);
        this.allowField.processPath(path);
        this.allowField2.processPath(path);
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#processRecord
    processRecord: function(record, path) {
        alert("processRecord")
        console.log("CustomWidget#processRecord", path, record);
        this.allowField.processRecord(record, path);
        this.allowField2.processRecord(record, path);
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#setValue
    setValue: function(value) {

        alert("value ==>> "+value)


        //alert("setValue"+parts[0]+" = "+parts[1]+" = "+parts[2]+ " = "+parts[3]+" = "+parts[4])

var currentPath = window.location.pathname+window.location.search;
            var curl = currentPath.split('.html');
            var suppressForbiddenCheck = true;
                    alert(curl[0])
            CQ.shared.HTTP.get(curl[0]+'/jcr:content/context-price.3.json', 
            function(options, success, response) {
              //  console.log(options); // Request options
                //console.log(success); // true/false
                //console.log(response); // Response obj


                if(response.body != null){
                    console.log("json data ======>> "+response.body)
                    var json = JSON.parse(response.body);

                    var key, val, context, count = 0;
                    var stringified;
                    for(key in json.context){
                      if(json.context.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        console.log("key - "+key+" ,value - "+json.context[key])
                         // stringified = JSON.stringify(key);
                            val = json.context[key];
                                //this.context1.set
                             // console.log("stringified -->> "+value+" == "+stringified) 
                              console.log(key + " : " + val)

                                for(context in val){
                                  if(val.hasOwnProperty(context)) {
                                      var temp = context;
                                      if(temp.indexOf("price") != -1) {
                                         // this.price1 = val[context];

                                            this.otherField.setValue(val[context]);
                                           console.log(context+"------------"+this.price1)
                                      }

                                          if(temp.indexOf("context") != -1){
                                           //  this.context1 = val[context];

                                                this.allowField2.setValue(val[context]);
                                             console.log(context+"------------"+this.context1)
                                          }

                                  }
                                }

                          //}

                        count++;
                      }
                    }
               //      console.log("logging-- "+ count)

                }

                if(success) {
                    // eval turns JSON response to JS Obj
                   // var myPage = CQ.shared.HTTP.eval(response);
                    //console.log(myPage['jcr:primaryType'])
                 //   console.log('url success ==>> '+response.body)
                }else{
                   // console.log('falied to get url')
                }
            }, this, suppressForbiddenCheck);
        var parts = value.split("/");
            //this.allowField.setValue(parts[0]);
            //this.allowField2.setValue(parts[1]);
            //this.otherField.setValue(parts[2]);
            this.allowField.setValue("fr");
            //this.allowField2.setValue(parts[0]);
            //this.otherField.setValue(parts[1]);
            this.hiddenField.setValue(value);
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getValue
    getValue: function() {
        alert("getValue")
        return this.getRawValue();
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getRawValue
    getRawValue: function() {
        alert("getRawValue")


        if (!this.allowField) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!this.allowField2) {
            return null;
        }

       // return (this.context1 + "/" + this.price1);

    return (this.allowField.getValue() + "/" + 
    this.allowField2.getValue()+ "/" +this.otherField.getValue() + "/" 
    +this.price1 + "/" + this.context1);
        },

             //private
    updateHidden: function() {
    alert("updateHidden")
    this.hiddenField.setValue(this.getValue());
        }
    });

// register xtype
CQ.Ext.reg('testfield', Ejst.CustomWidget);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the node reference "./multishort", you can add listeners and code on its events.

Comment: Tushar: do you have any example of that sort? i browsed through adobe forums as much possible, couldnt find any